# CodeIgniter and undefined variables when inserting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and getting undefined variable errors for every field I'm trying to insert into a database. Is there something I'm missing?

E: Oh yeah, and most importantly, it will insert "NULL" on all fields in the database after form is submitted.

**Here's my view:**

```
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
<?php $attributes = array(
        'id' => 'add_user_form'
    );
?>

<?php echo form_open('users/add_user', $attributes); ?>

        <span class="close_form_button_add_user_form">X</span>


    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="text" name="f_name" placeholder="Etunimi" class="half-width" />
    <input type="text" name="l_name" placeholder="Sukunimi" class="half-width" style="float: right; margin-right: 24px;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Uuden käyttäjän sähköpostiosoite" class="user full-width" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="email" name="email_confirm" placeholder="Sähköpostiosoite uudelleen" class="user full-width" />
    </div>

    <div class="form_row">
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Puhelinnumero (0401234567)" class="full-width" />
    </div>


    <div class="form_row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
    <select name="user_type" class="add_user_select" id="select_user_type">
    <option value="">Käyttäjätyyppi</option>
    <option value="admin">Hallinto</option>
    <option value="moderator">Hallinto 2</option>
    <option value="enduser">Pääkäyttäjä</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="add_user" value="Luo käyttäjä" class="login_submit" id="submit_user" style="margin: 5px 24px 0px 0px;"/>
    </div>

    <div class="form_row" id="add_user_optional_information">
    <select name="school" class="add_user_select half-width">
    <option value="">Koulutalo</option>
    <?php  foreach($schools as $school) :?>
        <option value="<?=$school['id']?>"><?=$school['name']?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>

    <select name="subject" class="add_user_select half-width">
    <option value="">Laji</option>
    <?php  foreach($subjects as $subject) :?>
        <option value="<?=$subject['id']?>"><?=$subject['subject_name']?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    </div>
     <?php echo form_close(); ?>


    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    </div>
```

**Here's my model for adding user into database (called user):**

```
<?php

    class User extends CI_Model {

        public function add_user() {

            $data = array(
                    'username' => $username,
                    'name' => $name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'password' => $password,
                    'user_type' => $user_type,
                    'phonenumber' => $phonenumber,
                    'school_id' => $school_id,
                    'subject_id' => $subject_id
                );

            $this->db->insert('users', $data);
        }
    }
?>
```

**And my controller to handle the actual inserting: (ignore the comments)**

```
    <?php

        class Users extends CI_Controller {
           public function add_user() 
           {

            if($this->input->post('add_user'))
            {

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

      $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_name', 'Etunimi', 'required|min_length[2]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('l_name', 'Sukunimi','required|min_length[3]');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Sähköpostiosoite','required|matches[email_confirm]|is_unique[users.email]|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_confirm', 'Sähköpostiosoite', 'required|valid_email');
      $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_number', 'Puhelinnumero', 'min_length[7]|max_length[10]');


            if($this->input->post('user_type') == "moderator")
            {   

                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('school', 'Koulutalo', 'required');
                    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Laji', 'required');
            }

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {

                echo "Not working!!";
            }

            $first_part_username = substr($this->input->post('f_name'), 0, 2);
            $second_part_username = substr($this->input->post('l_name'), 0, 3);
            $random_number = random_string('numeric', 4);

            $username = $first_part_username . $second_part_username . $random_number;

            $password = random_string('alnum', 8);


            $this->load->model('user');

                $data = array (
                    'name'          => strtoupper($this->input->post('f_name')). " ".strtoupper($this->input->post('lname')),
                    'email'         => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'username'      => $username,
                    'password'      => $this->phpass->hash($password),
                    'user_type'     => $this->input->post('user_type'),
                    'phone_number'  => $this->input->post('phone_number'),
                    'school_id'     => $this->input->post('school_id'),
                    'subject_id'    => $this->input->post('subject_id')
                    );


                    if($this->user->add_user($data))
                    {
                        $this->load->library('email');

                        $config['newline'] = '\r\n';
                        $this->email->initialize($config);

                        $this->email->from('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
                        $this->email->to($this->input->post('email'));  
                        $this->email->subject('Käyttäjä rekisteröity');
                        $this->email->message(
                        "Hei," 
                        .strtoupper($this->input->post('f_name')). " ".strtoupper($this->input->post('l_name')).".
                        Tämä on automaattinen viesti kilpailuvastaavan toimesta. \n
                        Olemme luoneet sinulle palveluumme käyttäjätunnuksen ja salasanan, jonka avulla pääset käsiksi
                        infrastruktuurijärjestelmään. \n
                        Pääset kirjautumaan järjestelmään seuraavilla tunnuksilla:"

                        );  


                    if($this->email->send()) {

                        base_url().'dashboard';
                    }
                }

                }
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
                $this->load->view('footer');

           }
        }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `$data` from `Controller` to your `Model` but you haven't defined any `parameter` you receiving in your `Model`. Change model function to this -

```
public function add_user($data) {

        $data = array(
                'username' => $data['username'],
                'name' => $data['name'],
                'email' => $data['email'],
                'password' => $data['password'],
                'user_type' => $data['user_type'],
                'phonenumber' => $data['phone_number'],
                'school_id' => $data['school_id'],
                'subject_id' => $data['subject_id']
            );

        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling $this->user->add_user($data) but your model function definition is public function add_user() , it should be public function add_user( $data )